# No he podido con este problema

Tags: java

Debo hacer un programa que tenga un arreglo con 10 numeros. El arreglo se llena a partir de entradas y tan pronto como termine de llenar el arreglo el programa debe imprimir la posición en la cual se encuentra el numero mayor....
Hasta el momento solo he podido llenar las entradas, he intentado comparar los elementos dentro del arreglo pero no he podido, no se como hacerlo... Esto es lo que llevo del programa:

```
    package main;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
        static int [] numeros = new int [10];
        public static void main(String[]args) {
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++ ) {
                System.out.print("Llene el arreglo por favor: ");
                numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt(); //Se llena el arreglo
            }
            // Se recorre el arreglo para mirar donde esta el numero mas grande
            /**for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
               int mayor = 0;
               if(numeros[mayor] > numeros [i] ) {
            System.out.println("El numero mayor esta en la posicion: " + numeros[i]);
               }
               }*/
    
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Agrego código comentado.

```
package main;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    static int[] numeros = new int[10];
    
    // 1. Agregar variable para guardar el mayor
    int mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // 2. Agregar variable para guardar la posicion
    int posicion = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Llene el arreglo por favor: ");
            numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt(); //Se llena el arreglo

            // 3. evaluar aquí si el número ingresado es mayor
            // que el actual mayor y actualizar
            if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = numeros[i];
                // 4. guardar la posicion actual
                posicion = i;
            }
        }
        // 5. imprimir la posicion del numero mayor
        System.out.println("El numero mayor esta en la posicion " + posicion);
    }
}
```

Actualización:

> Como hace mayor para interactuar con el arreglo si no esta adentro de
> el?

No lo hace. La variable mayor es independiente al arreglo. Lo único que tiene en común con el arreglo es que `mayor` también está dentro del ciclo for por lo que se aprovecha para calcular su valor al mismo tiempo que se va llenando el arreglo.

> ¿Porque se iguala la variable con el arreglo?

La variable `mayor` no se iguala con el arreglo. Se iguala con el elemento del arreglo en la posición `i` la cual contiene el número recién ingresado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, espero no molestar... pero quede con unas dudas y te agradeceria que me lo expliques por favor.
En el condicional y en la linea de codigo de abajo no entiendo muy bien lo que pasa...
Como hace mayor para interactuar con el arreglo si no esta adentro de el ?
Mi otra pregunta es: ¿Porque se iguala la variable con el arreglo?

Comment: Agregué unas explicaciones a la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

facil necesitas un sentinel que este pendiente de la posicion

array = (a0. a1 ...an)
al inicio tu numero mayor va ser a0

```
ENTONCES 
sentinel =  0;
mayor = a[0]
for i = 1 hasta n-1
   si mayor <a[i]
     sentinel = i
     mayor = a[i]
```

si sentinel no cambia osea siempre es 0 en la 0 esta el mayor puedes hacerlo así pero si es un array grande lo mejor es hacer *divide and conquer*

Answer (score 1):

Veo que ya respondieron esta pregunta pero creo que es importante que recuerdes que en los arreglos se empieza a contar desde el 0 y no desde el 1. Yo le agregaría una pequeña suma ya que, puede dar error por un valor, la ubicación del numero más alto por -1.

Te dejo el código, espero te sirva:

```
    int NumeroMayor = 0;
    int Posicion = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++ ) {
        if (numeros[i] >= NumeroMayor) {
            NumeroMayor = numeros[i];
            Posicion = i+1;
        }
```

Saludos.